# Custom Data Binding in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, data-binding, spring-restcontroller

I have a situation here. Suppose, I'm receiving this JSON in the `@RequestBody`,

```
{
    "resourceId": "R0001",
    "refs": [
        {
            "username": "infinite-despair",
            "roleType": "3"
        },
        {
            "username": "faith-knight",
            "roleType": "2"
        },
        .
        .
        .

    ]
}
```

Which I'm binding to a POJO, like so.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<SomeModel> addRefs(@RequestBody @Valid ResourceRefRequest req) {...}
```

Now, `ResourceRefRequest`, is as follows,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ResourceRefRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "Resource ID is required")
    private String resourceId;

    @NotEmpty
    private List<@Valid RefReqItem> refs;
}
```

and, `RefReqItem`, is as follows,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RefReqItem {

    private String resourceId;

    @NotNull(message = "Username is required")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "Role is required")
    private Integer roleType;
}
```

Things are pretty well, as I expect them to be. The only problem is, `refReqItem.resourceId` is `null`, for all `refs`. I want to populate each of, `refReqItem.resourceId`, in the `refs`, with the one at the root; namely, with, `resourceRefRequest.resourceId`. Any idea, how can we achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ResourceRefRequest`, you can create a special setter for your JSON handler to use, to do your own post-processing in code:

```
    @JsonSetter("refs")
    public void setRefsWithResourceId(List<RefReqItem> refs) {
        this.refs = refs.stream()
            .map(ref -> {
                ref.setResourceId(resourceId);
                return ref;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

When creating the Java object from JSON, this setter will be called because the method has the signature of a setter and is annotated with `@JsonProperty("refs")`.